# I am coding a website. The URL for the background image is in the CSS style sheet. I can't get the image to show

Tags: html, css, url, background-image

```
 <!-- First Parallax Image with Logo Text -->
   <div class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min" id="home">
     <div class="w3-display-middle" style="white-space:nowrap;">
       <span class="w3-center w3-padding-large w3-black w3-xlarge w3-wide 
 w3-animate-opacity">Lori 
  <span class="w3-hide-small">Roberg</span> - Web Designer and 
 Developer</span>
    </div>
 </div>





 /*css code*/
 /* First image (Logo. Full height) */
enter code here
 .bgimg-1 {
   background-image:url('images/flpic.png');
   min-height: 100%;
 }
```

I can not get the flpic.png background image to display.I have tried many different urls - such as - ('/images/flpic.png'),  ('../images/flpic.png') and the one above. My file structure is HTML5 index.html, style.css and a folder named images.

Comment: I saved the original code from a template under the following link:
File has been saved to: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G66YNXR9NEMO

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think the property is `background`

```
.bgimg-1 {
    background:url("/images/flpic.png");
}
```

Comment: Actually background: is the short hand version. I tried your suggestion. It still did not work.

Comment: My file structure looks like this:

Answer (score 0):

With the way URLs need to be structured, try the following:

- Current Directory: `./`
- Back Directory: `../`
- Forward Directory: `/`

My suggestion is to use `url(./images/flpic.png)`

Comment: I tried all these. They are not working. I wish I could post the full code. Maybe it is not in the url which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+I` should pull up the dev tools. Reload the page then see if it gives you an error.

Comment: @Lori I had a bit of an epiphany with @Ahamed's comment. Please try using `background-image:url('images/flpic.png') !important;`

Comment: After reviewing the update I noticed there was an issue with the images loading on w3. I don't think it's the issue that you were having specifically, but I was able to get the images to load by using an actual URL. If all else fails, you can do that. Here's a link to the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14uwyfbr/).

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed something from the link you provided. They have used custom css file. Add the following code inside your  if your haven't added it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```